# Como gerar boletos do Banco do Brasil com registro em PHP?

Tags: php, boleto

Tenho um sistema de gestão de planos de saúde que, entre outras coisas, tem um módulo de vendas onde se cadastra novos clientes e o sistema gera 12 boletos para o contrato de um ano. Esses boletos são gerados usando uma classe chamada OpenBoleto. O problema é que essa classe só gera boletos sem registro e com o fim desse tipo de boleto chegando, meu cliente pediu pra alterar a forma como as vendas são feitas, sendo que agora ele tem uma faixa de nosso número que o banco disponibilizou pra ele gerar os boletos com registro. A empresa enviará esses boletos para os clientes dela mensalmente. Porém não sei como gerar boleto com registro.

Não encontrei nenhuma classe em PHP ou algo do tipo que faça isso. Alguem tem uma classe que gere boletos com registro? Pode ser gerado em pdf ou direto na página.
O banco é o Banco do Brasil.

Comment: Existe uma classe chamada http://boletophp.com.br/ nela existem boletos para diversos bancos, dê uma olhada na documentação, espero que ajude, abraços.

Comment: Para gerar um boleto com registro você deve enviar arquivos para o banco através de EDI. Comece sua pesquisa por **EDI bancário de cobrança** que você estará no caminho certo. Aviso: é um esforço considerável se o seu sistema ainda não tiver isso implementado.

Comment: Para complementar... Não se trata de uma classe específica. O seu sistema deve gerar um arquivo em um formato específico (CNAB) e enviá-lo ao banco. O banco irá processar o envio e responder com outro arquivo no mesmo formato (que não necessariamente será montado no mesmo dia no qual você envia o seu arquivo). Você deve então interpretar a informação no arquivo retornado pelo banco para gerar os boletos.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque se trata de pedido de produto pronto, e não de dúvida de programação (poderia ser classificada como ampla demais, inclusive). Para adequar ao site, seria o caso de editar a pergunta e deixar claras as suas dúvidas sobre o procedimento em si. Lembre-se que pode editar a questão a qualquer momento, mesmo em caso de fechamento. O objetivo dos colegas é sempre ajudar, e o voto de fechamento não se trata de punição ou rejeição, apenas uma "pausa" para adequação. Os comentários anteriores dos colegas podem servir de ponto de partida.

Comment: Adicionalmente, basta uma consulta ao gerente da conta, que ele te encaminha toda a documentação do banco (ou consulta ao próprio site do banco). O site da Febraban também é uma boa referência aos padrões CNAB.de remessa. Note que há algumas iniciativas de se criarem APIs para isto, mas ainda não se chegou num consenso.